# Sharepoint 2013 Master Page

Tags: 2013

[image: I created a SharePoint document library, when user add items with long name the site will push to the Right, can someone please advice how to get this issue resolved?]

I created a SharePoint document library, when user add items with long name the site will push to the Right, can someone please advice how to get this issue resolved?

Comment: Find the container element. And set css `overflow:auto`. Also you should specify a width in percentage or pixel to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following CSS in the master page

```
#DeltaPlaceHolderMain {
    width: 400px; /*change this as per your design*/
    overflow: auto;
}
```